# How to show text verttically in Textview in Recyclerview in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I want to show list of Names in recyclerview.I've designed that Recyclerview  Item xml for that.But the problem is I want to show those names vertically in the single line(From the bottom to top).

I've tried by changing the angle(rotate attribute) of TextView.But it is not working on Recyclerview.
Can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: show what you have tried, how do you rotate this text currently (which isn't working)

Comment: Post code what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally.I have to create a custom class extending `TextView`.We can achieve our goal through this.

This is my class:

```
public class NewVerticalView extends TextView {
    private Rect bounds = new Rect();
    private TextPaint textPaint;
    private int color;

    public NewVerticalView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public NewVerticalView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        color = getCurrentTextColor();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        textPaint = getPaint();
        textPaint.getTextBounds((String) getText(), 0, getText().length(), bounds);
        setMeasuredDimension((int) (bounds.height() + textPaint.descent()), bounds.width());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        textPaint.setColor(color);
        canvas.rotate(-90,bounds.width(),0
        );
        canvas.drawText((String) getText(), 0,- bounds.width() + bounds.height(), textPaint);
    }
}
```